# Is the night prayer obligatory or desirable?

Tags: salat, madhhab

I searched for this subject, but I found that the Hanbali, Maliki, Shafi'i and Hanafi madhhab differed in the ruling on the night prayer.

- وقال تعالى: ﴿أَمَّنْ هُوَ قَانِتٌ ءانَاء ٱلَّيْلِ سَـٰجِداً وَقَائِماً يَحْذَرُ ٱلآخِرَةَ وَيَرْجُواْ رَحْمَةَ رَبّهِ قُلْ هَلْ يَسْتَوِى ٱلَّذِينَ يَعْلَمُونَ وَٱلَّذِينَ لاَ يَعْلَمُونَ﴾ [الزمر:9]

The Almighty said: "He is safe, he is a priest, a prostitute, a prostitute, and he who preaches the Hereafter, and pleases the mercy of his Lord. Say: Are they equal to those who know and those who do not know?" [Al-Zumar: 9]

1- عن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه قال: قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم:

أفضل الصيام ، بعد رمضان ، شهر الله المحرم . وأفضل الصلاة ، بعد الفريضة ، صلاة الليل

الراوي: أبو هريرة المحدث: مسلم - المصدر: صحيح مسلم - الصفحة أو الرقم: 1163
1- From Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) who said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:
The best fast, after Ramadan, the month of God Muharram. The best prayer, after the obligatory prayer, is the night prayer.
Narrator: Abu Hurayrah Hadith: Muslim - Source: Sahih Muslim - page or number: 1163

Is the night prayer obligatory or desirable?

Comment: It is certainly not obligatory by all madhhabs. There are only five obligatory prayers. Consider editing your post. The quran verse you quote is an invitation to do night prayers not an order and the hadith too. See for example [Taraweeh in mosque](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32602/is-it-obligatory-to-pray-taraweeh-in-the-mosque´), [Taraweeh for women](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25516/is-taraweeh-for-women-considered-as-sunnat-or-nafil) and [Time for optional night prayer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13210/what-is-the-best-time-for-optional-night-prayer)

Comment: Your exemple talk about tarawih but my question is about night prayer Medi1Saif♦

Comment: Not all of them and the question I've posted already asks about the **optional** night prayer! Basically the argumentation for both is the same. Beside this the fact that there are only 5 obligatory prayers already make your question meaningless.

Comment: But that question is about the time of the night prayer, but I am looking to find <if night prayer obligatory or desirable>Medi1Saif♦

Comment: And I'm saying from my first comment on that as there are only five obligatory prayers namely: fajr/sobh, dhohr, 'asr, maghrib and 'isha' (which are all mentioned in the quran) the night prayer per se is not obligatory.so your question doesn't make sense. Beside this the verse and hadith you mentioned shows that it is desirable as the wording doesn't indicate an order but says it is better to do so.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones what qualifies that question to be a duplicate? Witr is not the night prayer OP is referring to.

Comment: @Medi1Saif: What else could "the night prayer" mean (if it's not tarawih according to [this comment](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45148/is-the-night-prayer-obligatory-or-desirable#comment75830_45148))?  [Tahajjud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahajjud)?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I guess OP himself is unclear about that, the point is taraweeh, tahajjud are synonyms of night prayer, but they are commonly used for the night prayers before or after 'Isha' in Ramadan which might create a confusion.

Comment: I know it has been a while since you posted this, but please, the translation of Surah Al Zumar is extremely way off and very offensive. Please read what you have posted, you have equated prostitution to other aspects of the deen.

Answer (score 2):

There are five [*fard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fard) (obligatory) prayers in Sunni Islam:

> You have to offer perfectly the five compulsory prayers in a day and night (24 hours), unless you want to pray Nawafil.
>   <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 1891](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/1)</sub>

Indeed, the hadith cited in the question confirms that the night prayer ([tahajjud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahajjud)) is voluntary:

> ... the most excellent prayer after what is prescribed is prayer during the night.
>   <sub>[Sahih Muslim 1163 a](https://sunnah.com/muslim/13/261)</sub>

It's described in the Qur'an as "additional":

> And from [part of] the night, pray with it as additional [worship] for you; it is expected that your Lord will resurrect you to a praised station.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 17:79](https://quran.com/17/79); see [IslamAwakened](https://www.islamawakened.com/quran/17/79/) for other translations</sub>

It's widely described as voluntary (but recommended) in Sunni fatawa: [SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2010/08/05/tahajjud-prayer-description-merits/), [Fatwa.ca](http://fatwa.ca/ibadiyat/a-mufti-said-that-if-one-did-not-sleep-after-isha-then-his-night-prayers-will-not-be-tahajud-rather-qayam-ul-lail-could-you-clarify/), [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/232094), [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=339823), [Qibla.com](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/36245), [Darul Iftaa](http://www.daruliftaa.com/node/6182).

Comment: Does Nawafil means volunteer prayers? Or what?

Comment: "[Nawafil](http://www.alahazrat.net/islam/the-book-of-prayer-chapter-6.php)" refers to "voluntary" or "optional".  I'm used to "[nafl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nafl_prayer)"; you might get a better answer from someone with more Arabic knowledge.