# Extended night time salat mentioned in Quran; Isha, Subh, Layl, fard, Terewih, or Nafila?

Tags: quran, salat, practical-islam

I am confused about the night time prayers mentioned in the Quran.  From Yusuf Ali's English translation:

073.002 Stand (to prayer) by night, but not all night,-

073.003 Half of it,- or a little less,

073.004 Or a little more; and recite the Qur'an in slow, measured rhythmic tones.

073.020 Thy Lord doth know that thou standest forth (to prayer) nigh two-thirds of the night, or half the night, or a third of the night, and so doth a party of those with thee.

076.026
And part of the night, prostrate thyself to Him; and glorify Him a long night through.

Are these only for our prophet?  If not just for our prophet, thus recommended for all Muslims, how do we classify these salat, and how much of the night, and what part of the night?

Comment: The verses simply show the chronology of stages from the night prayer being mandatory until it became optional. This is a relevant post [Is the night prayer obligatory or desirable](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45148/is-the-night-prayer-obligatory-or-desirable) at the time I've read the post i misunderstood and had little knowledge on the matter actually I was preparing an answer for it, but had no time to give it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the prayers you mentioned are for ther prophet.
Here is all our prayers at night.

First: prayers we must do (Fard *literally meanning must be done*)

1. Maghrib: its time is when the sun sets and the night just begins.
2. Isha: its time is after maghrib and  before midnight.
3. Fajr: and its time is before the sun rises.

Second: additional prayers that we may do (Sunnah *literally meanning optional, following our prophet* , we pray them because the prophet did but if we don't pray them there is no problem.

1. Nafila: and its time is 2 raq'ahs just after maghrib, 2 just after Isha, and 2 just before Fajr.
2. Watr: any odd number of raq'ahs after the nafila of the Isha. (1, 3, 5, ...) most muslims pray 3.
3. Tarweeh: is 8 to 20 raq'ahs after Isha by at least half an hour. It is very very desirable and rewarding esecially in Ramadan.
4. Subh: it is for those who missed Fajr because they were asleep, and its time is when they wake up (2 raq'ahs).

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support your claims? (see [answer]). You answer the wrong question without addressing the actual question asked which is about the meaning of these verses which seem to contradict to what we now know as established worship.

Comment: I answered what the asker wanted, and he selected it as an accepted answer. As for the evidence here it is dear brother: https://muflihun.com/riyadussaliheen/2/33. I do not see a nessecity in lengthening my answer.

Comment: A basis of our model is the peer review, so if OP accepts an answer that might mean it was useful to him or he just is happy to have an answer this doesn't actually means that the community accepts it or regards it as useful. Therefore we can up- or down-vote answers and questions.

Comment: @Medi1Saif you are right. I checked How to Answer link you provided. I however need you to tell me how to make my answer better.

Comment: It seems to me that you discovered the **Edit** link below your post using it is the first step. I'm not aware of a link I've provided at least not for this post